# SQL (MySql) foreign key and composite key syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong here. The error that I am getting is:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Cast( movieId int, actorId int, salary decimal(7,2) default '77777.77', fore' at line 1

```
create table Cast(
movieId int,
actorId int,
salary decimal(7,2) default '77777.77',
primary key(movieId,actorId)
foreign key(actorId) references Actor(actorId),
foreign key(movieId) references Movie(movieId)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Cast(...` with no space between `Cast` and the `(`, MySQL thinks you are trying to use the [`CAST()` builtin function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html). That makes no sense following `CREATE TABLE`, so MySQL is confused.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html

If you put a space before the paren, that fixes that problem.

```
create table Cast (
                 ^
```

You also have another minor mistake, you forgot a comma after your PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: bill-> he is also missing a comma on end of this line primary key(movieId,actorId)

Comment: @SeanCh, thanks, didn't I mention that at the end of my answer?